# Pular o primeiro caractere da linha

Tags: c, char, scanf

Estou tentando ler um arquivo, pegar algumas informações e colocar em variavéis, mas não estou conseguindo, pois cada linha do meu arquivo começa com um caractere que preciso pular.

O arquivo de entrada é assim:

[image: input.txt]

Eu preciso ignorar os "T" e pegar apenas os números. Já tentei usar `%*c` no `fscanf`, mas não deu certo.

```
int initialize()
{
    int n, n1, n2, n3, i = 0;
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("input.txt", "r");
    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error locating the file. Please try again!\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    while (fscanf(fp, "%d, %d, %d", &n1, &n2, &n3) != EOF)
    {

        p[i] = n1;

        if (p[i] > MAX)
        {
            printf("Woah! I am not a super computer. Please input upto 100 processes :)\n");
            exit(1);
        }

        b[i] = n2;

        a[i] = n3;
        i++;
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return i;
}
```

Comment: poste algo completo, compilável. E não poste uma imagem de um arquivo de 3 linhas, poste o texto de 3 linhas. Ajude outros a ajudarem você

Answer (score 3):

> *Já tentei usar `%*c` no fscanf, mas não deu certo.*

De fato, se você usar `"%*c%d, %d, %d"`, na primeira linha até funciona, pois ele ignora o "T". O problema é que o `fscanf` não vai consumir o caractere de quebra de linha (que está no final da linha). Então na segunda iteração, `%*c` vai ignorar a quebra de linha e não o "T".

Uma alternativa é colocar um espaço no início:

```c
while (fscanf(fp, " %*c%d, %d, %d", &n1, &n2, &n3) == 3) {
    // etc...
}
```

Repare no espaço antes do `%*c`, isso faz com que ele ignore quaisquer *whitespace characters* (o que inclui a quebra de linha).

Outro detalhe é que o retorno de `fscanf` é a quantidade de valores que foram corretamente lidos. Como estou lendo três números, comparei o retorno com `3`. Se não for `3` é porque não conseguiu ler 3 números, então não faria sentido continuar (nesse caso, ele vai parar a leitura no meio do arquivo, por exemplo, caso alguma linha não esteja no formato esperado).

---

Outra alternativa é usar [`fgets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) para ler a linha inteira, e depois usar `sscanf` para processá-la:

```c
// buffer para guardar a linha (criar com tamanho adequado, usei "20" como exemplo)
char buffer[20];
while (fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, fp) != NULL && sscanf(buffer + 1, "%d, %d, %d", &n1, &n2, &n3) == 3) {
    // etc...
}
```

Ou seja, primeiro `fgets` lê a linha inteira (se não conseguir ler, já para por aí). Depois, eu ignoro o primeiro caractere: veja que no `sscanf` eu passo `buffer + 1`, que faz com que pegue do segundo caractere em diante. Desta forma, não preciso mais do `%*c`, posso deixar apenas os `%d`.

Nesse caso, se o `sscanf` não conseguir ler três números, o *loop* se encerra e **o restante do arquivo não é lido**. Claro que se o arquivo é bem formado, não haverá problema, mas caso não seja, deve-se analisar o que fazer. Por exemplo, se for para simplesmente ignorar a linha e passar para a próxima, aí seria:

```c
char buffer[20];
// diferente do código acima, este não para de ler o arquivo caso a linha não tenha 3 números
while (fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, fp) != NULL) {
    if (sscanf(buffer + 1, "%d, %d, %d", &n1, &n2, &n3) == 3) {
        // conseguiu ler, faz algo com os números
    } else {
        /* Não conseguiu ler, mostra alguma mensagem, faz alguma outra coisa?
           Ou, se não for para fazer nada e só ir para a próxima linha,
           simplesmente remova o else */
    }
}
```

---

Por fim, pode ser que o resultado de `fgets` seja uma string vazia, então você pode incluir esta verificação antes do `sscanf`:

```c
while (fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, fp) != NULL && *buffer != '\0' && sscanf(buffer + 1, "%d, %d, %d", &n1, &n2, &n3) == 3)
```

Isso é só para garantir que se a string é vazia (ou seja, se o primeiro caractere é o terminador de string - é isso que `*buffer != '\0'` verifica), eu nem chamo o `sscanf`. Ou ainda poderia trocar para `*buffer == 'T'`, assim ele só chama o `sscanf` se o primeiro caractere for um "T".

Answer (score 3):

Usando essas funções da família `scanf()` evite comparar o valor de retorno com `EOF`. Prefira sempre comparar com o total de especificadores presentes na "máscara" (o segundo parâmetro).

[Outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/554757/112052) mostra uma boa possibilidade usando `fgets` para consumir as linhas e `sscanf` para extrair os valores

### 2 EXEMPLOS

Vou deixar mais dois exemplos abaixo, um pouco mais genéricos e usando uma função apenas. São mais genéricos pela maneira de tratar os prefixos:

- a primeira função extrai qualquer número de letras antes do primeiro dígito no primeiro campo
- a segunda função faz a mesma coisa para todos os campos
- as 2 funções aceitam qualquer número de campos por linha. Claro que é trivial modificar para fixar o total em 3 (seu caso) ou (o mais comum) fixar o total como sendo o total de campos encontrados na primeira linha
- O código funciona com qualquer delimitador
- as 2 funções aceitam o nome do arquivo e o delimitador como parâmetros porque é mais prático

#### Os protótipos

```
int initialize(const char*,const char);
int initialize2(const char*,const char);
```

#### Resumo

`main` é algo simples como

```
int main(void) { return initialize2("x.txt", ','); };
```

Como é só um exemplo a função retorna -1 se não abrir o arquivo e -2 se não conseguir ler nenhum campo, e assim se pode ver o erro na console.

`scanf` e família foram escritas para consumir dados tabulares, como arquivos CSV. As funções abaixo leêm campo a campo usando `fscanf()` com essa especificação

```
    const char* mask = "%[^X\n]%c";
    mask[3]          = simbolo;
```

onde `simbolo` é o delimitador em uso, a vírgula aqui.

O exemplo abre o arquivo e le os campos, usando `atoi` para converter e testa o delimitador --- o segundo especificador --- para saber se terminou a linha ou não. Assim é simples tratar outros cenários, como fixar o total de campos ou converter para vários formatos, como é o caso de arquivos CSV. Desse contexto essa função foi extraída.

#### EXEMPLO 1

```
#define NEW_LINE_ 10
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int initialize(const char*, const char);

int main(void) { return initialize("v.txt", ','); };

int initialize(const char* f_name, const char simbolo)
{
    char mask[]      = "%[^X\n]%c";
    mask[3]          = simbolo;
    char  buffer[80] = {0};
    int   delim      = 0;
    FILE* fp         = fopen(f_name, "r");
    if (NULL == fp) return -1;  // nao abriu
    int res = fscanf(fp, mask, buffer, &delim);
    if (res != 2) return -1;  // nao leu nada
    int campo1 = 1;  // primeiro campo pode ter letras
    while (res == 2)
    {
        int   val = 0;
        char* p   = buffer;
        if (campo1)
        {
            while (*p != 0)
            {
                if ((*p >= '0') && (*p <= '9')) break;
                p += 1;
            }
            campo1 = 0;
        }
        else if (delim == NEW_LINE_)
            campo1 = 1;
        val = atoi(p);
        printf("%d ", val);
        if (delim == NEW_LINE_) printf("\n");
        res = fscanf(fp, mask, buffer, &delim);
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

#### `v.txt`

```
T1, 3, 0
T2, 3, 1
T3, 2, 2
```

#### Saída

```
1 3 0
2 3 1
3 2 2
```

#### EXEMPLO 2

```
#define NEW_LINE_ 10
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int initialize2(const char*, const char);

int main(void) { return initialize2("x.txt", ','); };

int initialize2(const char* f_name, const char simbolo)
{
    char mask[]      = "%[^,\n]%c";
    mask[3]          = simbolo;
    char  buffer[80] = {0};
    int   delim      = 0;
    FILE* fp         = fopen(f_name, "r");
    if (NULL == fp) return -1;  // nao abriu
    int res = fscanf(fp, mask, buffer, &delim);
    if (res != 2) return -2;  // nao leu nada
    while (res == 2)
    {
        int   val = 0;
        char* p   = buffer;
        while (*p != 0)
        {
            if ((*p >= '0') && (*p <= '9')) break;
            p += 1;
        }
        val = atoi(p);
        printf("%d ", val);  // o campo lido
        if (delim == NEW_LINE_) printf("\n");
        res = fscanf(fp, mask, buffer, &delim);
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

#### `x.txt`

```
Teste T1,20,36565
T4,5,6
Stack Overflow 7,8,-091
Stack 1,Overflow 2,3 Stack,4,5,6,7 FIM
```

#### Saida

```
1 20 36565
4 5 6
7 8 91
1 2 3 4 5 6 7
```

Comment: Quando eu levo um voto negativo sei que provavelmente realizei uma ou mais ações moderativas junto aos conteúdos do votante. Porém o arfneto não fecha perguntas, ele quase não vota e nunca fez uma sinalização, então não há motivos para receber hate. Por favor veja o esforço que dispendido na confecção da reposta e se encontrou algum problema com a resposta não precisa de imediato remover o negativo, mas deixe uma orientação para que o usuário melhore sua solução e possa reverter o seu voto.

Comment: @AugustoVasques **UP**. Concordo e apoio. A resposta foi uma boa explicação e alternativa de resposta.